# Navigate through table pagination with Html Agility Pack (HAP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, html-agility-pack

I have this table which I'm already accessing all elements that can be seen on first page, but I have no idea how to navigate through the next pages, as the data from them are not present in the HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument element that I'm getting with the Load method.

URL: https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/wege3

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8zgv.png)

Comment: HAP is an html parser. It will not help you if the html is not loaded beforehand. To interact with the web page in order for the desired htmls to be loaded, you need tools like [selenium webdriver](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/) (c# port).

Comment: thanks, will have a look into that :)